# How do I make Outlook 2010 send email immediately (rather than letting message stay in OutBox)?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

This is when Outlook 2010 is closed -- I compose a new message via another Windows app, e.g. clicking on a mailto: link in the browser.

I got an Outlook "New Message" window, after I click 'Send' the window closes but it doesn't actually send the email until next time I start Outlook.

How do you make it send immediately when Outlook is not running?

Comment: I am having the same problem and the answer below is no help. The document is not sent before I actually start Outlook 2010 the next time. I noticed that Outlook 2010 does not know the nicknames when I send via Explorer context menu. I don't get any proposed mail addresses when entering the recipient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible. The entire infrastructure of Outlook is based around mail activity only happening while the app is running.

There are certainly other applications which run as services that let you send email anytime, and even take over the mailto: handlers, but that's probably not what you want.

Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Open Outlook Click on the File menu –> Options then Navigate to Advanced tab and scrolled down to Send and receive section then click on the Send/Receive button. Using the Schedule an automatic send/receive every minutes field you can specify the time period to 1 minute which the automatic send/receive emails needs to be done. Default time is 30 minutes. This will be helpful for you.

Thanks